# Concatenate 2 Columns in VBA

Tags: vba, concatenation

I have 2 columns (column F and G), let's say they both go up to row 10. In row S, I want a concatenate statement: F(G)

I've tried:

`SHEET.range("S2:S2" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-13],""("",RC[-12],"")"")"`

and

`SHEET.column(18).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-13],""("",RC[-12],"")"")"`

The problem with either is that after the 10th row, the formula keeps running such that every cell goes "()". How do I edit the macro to end when there's no more data in column F and G?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with:

> `range("S2:S2" & LastRow)`

if `LastRow` is 10 then the string will be `S2:S210` as you have the `2` in the second reference.  You want to remove that:

```
range("S2:S" & LastRow)
```

So:

```
SHEET.range("S2:S" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-13],""("",RC[-12],"")"")"
```